# Reading array byte per byte

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to read an array per byte, however the array could be of any type larger than one byte.

Take for example the following code:

```
unsigned short numbers[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 
unsigned char* point = (unsigned char*) numbers;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    std::cout << (int) *point;
    point ++;
}
```

The array is of type `unsigned short`, thus each element is two bytes long. To read the continous data in memory, I try to use a one bit long `unsigned char`. Printing the 5 first bytes, I expect to have the output "01020", but I get "10203". The first byte is missing, but I don't know why. In my IDE, I checked the addres of `numbers` and `point`, and they both point to the same memory addres before the loop.

Comment: Because your machine is [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Atomic_element_size_8-bit_2)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your machine is little endian.

To understand it properly, let's check this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
   printf("%d",(int) *point);
   point ++;
   printf("%d",(int) *point);
   point ++;
  }
```

This will print the following output: `1020304050`

And since you are just incrementing the pointer `point` by single byte. Hence you are getting the first `5` byte as output which is `10203`.